# Notes on the Stack Overflow survey

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-overflow-developer-survey

Two minor points I noticed in the survey:

1. Question 2 is "How long have you worked in the software development / IT industry", while in question 3 I get asked what industry I am in -- which isn't neccessarily SD/IT.
2. You can only choose one answer in Question 5 ("What is your role your company's purchasing process?"), although the answers are neither mutually exlusive nor accumulatively implying each other (I hope you know what I mean).

**Update** for you non-believers:

[image: survey]

Comment: What survey are you talking about?

Comment: @jjnguy: That one.

Comment: Don't make me refresh until I see the ad. Just link to the damned survey, man!

Comment: http://www.surveymonkey.com/s/HN5CTC3

Comment: There, now doesn't it feel good to not be hallucinating surveys?

Comment: Looked through the survey... unfortunately, my opinion doesn't matter. ;-(

Comment: @Contact us: So I made you refresh this page until you saw the link?

Comment: @balpha: No, I was busy with other stuff, came back, and there it was. Trust me, I have other things to do than stalk Meta. Not *better* things, just *other* things.

Comment: yeah, right ...

Comment: so why isn't there a blog.stackoverflow.com post about this? and if they want people to take it, why not give everyone a one-time notification "would you be willing to take a 5-minute survey to help make stack overflow better?"

Comment: Queston #5 should be multiple choice. And in #6, annual budget for what? If you include salaries, then it's going to be way different than for hardware, or for software tools.

Comment: Yeah, I had no clue about the annual budget so I left that one blank.

Comment: @Kip - were I to do a survey, I'd do a small one first to get information on whether I made the survey correctly, and then adjust it accordingly and do the larger one.  They may be doing the same thing here.  Alternately, they are only interested in surveying people you pay attention to the sidebar ads, so a general announcement would mess that up.

Comment: Pollyanna is mostly correct. for now, we want the survey to be representative of SO visitors.

Answer (score 2):

To your first point: Because you are on Stack Overflow you must be doing some IT/software development work.  The next question is asking what industry you do this work in.

If I'm a developer of banking software, then I work in the banking industry.

Comment: What about the garbage man with his own little open source project? Or the student who's trying to improve her C++ skills? I, for one, although I do a little coding at work because I happen to have some such skills, am not employed as a developer.

Comment: Well, then choose the 'other' category

Comment: I did. So what do I put for "How long have you worked in the software development / IT industry?"

Comment: How ever long you have been writing code.

Comment: I wouldn't have considered myself part of the SD/IT industry when I was eight.

Comment: Well, neither would I.  Whenever you started writing code with a product in mind. (Or some goal of higher learning)  It isn't graded, just use your best judgment.

Comment: No, it's not graded. And my point is not "What should I have answered"; my point is that the results of a survey that cannot unambiguously be answered are flawed. My point is that the question(s) should be revised. To quote a very wise man: "People can come up with statistics to prove anything. 14% of people know that." SO obviously wants to present the results of this survey to their potential advertisers. If I was one of those, I'd say, "Oh yeah? 83% of your users have been in IT for more than 6 years? Can I see the survey questions, please?"

Comment: I agree that it is vague and poorly written.

Answer (score 1):

For #1:  Most software developers do it as support for some other industry.  My last job was as a programmer in the healthcare industry, for example.  Now I'm an IT Director in the Education industry.  I thought that was pretty clear, though I can see where it might puzzle a "pure" software developer.

For #2: The question has an "All of the above" answer that might fit better if you have that much influence.

Comment: I can "Specify/Select Products or Services" and "Evaluate Requirements" and "Help Define Needs" without having anything to do with the budget.