# Post the results of the SO survey on meta

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-developer-survey

Ok.  I know that there's some marketing-only stuff in the survey, but can we get the results of the survey posted to meta when it's complete?  Curious minds want to know.

Comment: I don't know if this is gonna fly.

Comment: Probably being thick/ignorant - but what survey?

Comment: @Dominic: http://www.surveymonkey.com/s/HN5CTC3 and also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34697/notes-on-the-stack-overflow-survey

Comment: The one that mysteriously and inexplicably assumes you work in a company, even if a large number of us don't?

Answer (score 1):

"some marketing-only stuff"? Except for the last question (which is pointless given meta), it's all marketing, i.e. the standard questions trade magazines get you to answer when you subscribe so they have solid facts to tell potential advertisers.

Comment: I guess I didn't consider the demographic stuff of only marketing interest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  Please!

It's possible, I suppose, that one might think there's value in keeping this info hidden, especially since they are doing the VC rounds, but I'm hopeful that some or all of this will be summarized on the blog or somewhere so the community can do more navel gazing.

We've got a pretty decent navel, all things considered, and it *deserves* some gazing.